# Remove space between two string and node in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to remove space between two string and node in XSLT. I am using XSLT 2.0

Input :

```
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234"><t/>AWS H <t/>(ever over)<t/></doc><refformat="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
```

Output should be :

```
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234"><t/>AWS H<t/>(ever over)<t/></doc><refformat="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
```

the space between `AWS H` and `<t/>` should be removed from output.

Comment: Use following code in top

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

Comment: normalize-space(actualSting) - This will do it

Comment: @AjeetSingh I used this before. But it was not working

Comment: use normalize-space(actualSting)

Comment: Can you be precise with what your actual requirement is? Do you want to remove trailing spaces from all text nodes, or just those that are followed by a `<t />` node? (Or maybe preceded by on too?)? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I want to remove the the space between `AWS H` and `<t/>` Final output should be `AWS H</t>`

Comment: Yes, but suppose it was `AWS K </t>` would the space need to be removed? Or `AWS H </s>`? Or maybe at the end you have `00 </p>`, would that space also need to be removed? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I don't want to do anything like `00 </p>` or `AWS H </s>`. I want to perform only remove space between `AWS K` and `</t>`. It means final output should be `AWS K</t>`

Comment: @user5000 FYI, there is no such thing as "space between string and node". In your example, `"AWS H "` is a **single text node** that includes **all** characters that exist between the two bordering `<t/>` elements - **including any whitespace characters**. Applying `normalize-space()` to this text node should strip any trailing (and leading) whitespace (in addition to replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space). If this is "not working" for you, you need to explain what you tried and how the result is different from what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the trailing space of any text node that is followed by a `<t />` node, you could do this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::t]]">
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+$', '')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you could use `normalize-space` here, instead of `replace`, but this would remove leading spaces too, which may or may not be want you want.

Note, if you only wanted to target text nodes beginning with `AWS` you could adjust the template match like so:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[starts-with(., 'AWS')][following-sibling::node()[1][self::t]]">
```

See this in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3W

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<ajeet>aaaaa </ajeet>
<kumar> bbbbb</kumar>
</root>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <singh><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//ajeet)"/></singh>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<singh>aaaaa</singh>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But still no working. Can we use regex for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
Try this using normalize-space
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code, space removal happen only between "text() node and <t>".:

Input XML:

```
<root>
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234">The <ii>pp</ii> the <t/>AWS H <t/>(ever over) <l>the </l><t/></doc><ref format="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234"><t/>AWS H <t/>(ever over)<t/></doc><ref format="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" 
            group-adjacent="exists(following-sibling::node()[1][self::t]) and self::text()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<root>
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234">The <ii>pp</ii>the<t/>AWS H<t/>(ever over) <l>the </l><t/></doc><ref format="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
<p type="c"><doc ref="core" id="k12234"><t/>AWS H<t/>(ever over)<t/></doc><ref format="no" ref="core" rid="ck1123"/>00</p>
</root>
```